# Typescript complaining about Absolute imports in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, absolute-path

So Im trying to implement Absolute imports using JSON files in directories.

In JSON:
`{"name": "components"}`

I have specified paths in config JSON, but still not working, I have tried with baseURL and without, with "/*" at the end:

````
"paths": {
      "components/*":["./src/components/*"]
    },```

and without:

"paths": {
      "components":["./src/components"]
    },
````

Code is working normally, only problem is TS error.

Comment: what is the name of the file, tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I usually do for my projects.

```
yarn add -D babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
        alias: {
          'components': './src/components',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* for module resolver */
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Restart VSCode

Comment: when I give the exact file path in the paths object under compilerOptions and in babel.config.js under alias it works fine but when I use component/* : ./src/components/* it did not work and gives me the error of Unable to resolve